# Ionic app side menu with a login page

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, ionic-framework

I am building an app that it's navigation based on a side menu. The problem I am having is trying to implement it along with a login page, that is not part of the side menu's scope, so that only after the login, the side menu navigation shall be used.

here's my app.js:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('signin', {
    url: '/sign-in',
    templateUrl: 'templates/sign-in.html',
    controller: 'SignInCtrl'
  })

  .state('sideMenu', {
    url: '/sideMenu',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/sideMenu.html',
    controller: 'sideMenuCtrl'
  })

  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'homeTabCtrl'
    })
  //})

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
})
```

This is the Side menu's HTML:

```
<ion-view ng-controller="sideMenuCtrl">
```

```
<ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-nav-bar type="bar-assertive" back-button-type="button-icon" back-button-icon="ion-arrow-left-c"></ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view>
  </ion-nav-view>
</ion-pane>

<!-- Left Side Menu -->
<ion-side-menu side="right">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
    <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content has-header="true">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-click="goTo(item.link)" class="item item-icon-left" ng-repeat="item in list" menu-close>
        <!-- <i ng-class="item.iconClass"></i> -->
        {{item.text}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

The controller:

```
  .controller('sideMenuCtrl', function ($scope, $location, MenuService) {
console.log('Side menu is reloaded');

// "MenuService" is a service returning mock data (services.js)
$scope.list = MenuService.all();

$scope.goTo = function(page) {
  console.log('Going to ' + page);
  $scope.sideMenuController.toggleLeft();
  $location.url('/' + page);
};
```

})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a small demo for you,

**[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HNVgdTmuHLD1q6BUP6GW?p=preview)**

**html**

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true " class="view-bg-blue">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="openMenu()"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content padding="true">
        <h3 class="text-center">Welcome To Landing Page</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h4>My App</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input placeholder="User">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input placeholder="password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="button icon-right ion-chevron-right button-calm" ng-click="open()">Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('tabs', {
            url: '/tab',
            controller: 'TabsCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
        })
        .state('tabs.home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'home-tab': {
                    controller: 'homeCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'home.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('tabs.settings', {
            url: '/settings',
            views: {
                'settings-tab': {
                    controller: ' signOutCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'settings.html'
                }
            }
        });
    $stateProvider
        .state('landing', {
            url: '/landing',
            controller: 'landingCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'landing.html'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/landing');
});
```

If you need any additional feature,Please let me know?Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a look and will let you know if I need anything.

Comment: how do you make it so it will work with a service and a ctrl.js?

Comment: @rcat24:Sorry I am not getting

Comment: I basically don't want to hard code the names and actions of each item in the menu, but I want to have a controller, that extracts it as a dictionary/array from a service. I have tried to call ng-controller, however for some reason, it does not take the information from the array.

Comment: Can you create a plunker example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95220/discussion-between-rcat24-and-muhsin).